# I keep getting the following error when running node index.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Error: "node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:458 Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object  at Function.use"

Code:

```
const express         = require('express');
const bodyParser      = require('body-parser');
const mustacheExpress = require('mustache-express');
const pgp                       = require('pg-promise');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = express(); 

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.engine('html', mustacheExpress());
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

const students = require('./controllers/students.js');
const houses = require('./controllers/houses.js');

app.use('/houses', houses);
app.use('/students', students);

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('home/index'));



app.listen(port, () => { console.log("Server started on " + port); });
module.exports = router;
```

**controllers/students.js:**
This is the first file which is linked to the index.js

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const Students = require('../models/students.js');


router.get('/', 
    Students.findAll, (req, res) => {
    res.render('students/index', {studentsData: res.locals.allStudentsData})
});

router.get('/:id', Students.findById, (req, res) => {
    res.render('students/show', res.locals.showStudent)
});

module.exports = router;
```

**controllers/houses.js:**
This is the second file which is linked to the index.js

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const Houses = require('../models/houses.js');


router.get('/', 
    Houses.findAll, (req, res) => {
    res.render('houses/index', {housesData: res.locals.allHousesData})
});

router.get('/:id', Houses.findById, (req, res) => {
    res.render('houses/show', res.locals.showHouse)
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: What's the content of controllers/students.js and controllers/houses.js?

Comment: Edit your question to format your comment please ;)

Comment: Just did :) in the question section

Comment: What's your express version? Check the value of require('./controllers/students.js') and require('./controllers/houses.js');

Comment: "express": "^4.16.1", this is my express version

Comment: I still don't know how to get it to work..

Comment: Can you put the full error message please?